# Glide path doesn't fit

Tags: android, path, android-glide

I've got a problem. I'm downloading an image from my website into an android-app
with the download-manager. As a destination, I put the following:

```
        request?.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS +
                    File.separator + ".my_app", name + ".jpg"
        )
```

and it works fine. the directory is now:

```
 file://storage/emulated/0/Download/.my_app/
```

However, if i put the same variables as arguments into Glide, like this:

```
    Glide.with(this)
        .load(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS +
                File.separator + ".my_app/" + name + ".jpg")
```

I receive an error like this:

```
W/Glide: Load failed for Download/.my_app/pic15.jpg with size [388x388]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 3 causes:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(/Download/.my_app/pic15.jpg (No such file or directory))
java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
```

It seems to me, like Glide doesn't note the part before "Download".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `Uri.parse(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS +
                File.separator + ".my_app/" + name + ".jpg")`.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response !
do you mean uri.parse() as the argument for load()? 
If I do that, i receive a new error-message:

W/Glide: Load failed for Download/.my_app/pic15.jpg with size [388x388]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.lang.NullPointerException(Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail

Comment: Yeah, but looks like `Glide` is not able to find image on that path.. verify your path first. Is your folder is accessible *(looks like you've got **.** Infront of my_app folder)*

Comment: Try this syntax instead `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ File.separator +".my_app/" + name + ".jpg"`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!